# Suppressing warnings for hadoop fs -get -p command

Tags: shell, unix, hadoop

I am copying huge number of files using hadoop fs -get -p command. I want to retain (timestamps, ownerships) Many of the files are not able to retain the permissions
as the userid are not available in the local machine. So for these files I am getting "get: chown: changing ownership /a/b/c.txt Operation not permitted)
Is it possible to suppress the error, because it might be possible that I might get other issues as well. If I do 2>/dev/null, this will suppress all the issues
So I don't want to use this option. Is there any way I can suppress ONLY issues related to Privileges.?

Any hint can be really helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very elegant, but functionnal, use `grep -v your_undesired_pattern`

```
hadoop fs -get -p command  2>&1 | grep  -v "changing ownership"
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Hadoop side, no.  The error is printed using `System.err.println` and is coming from the OS as the command execs `chown`.